# Related to the node.js experimental setup

Tags: node.js, express

I am following webdev simplified and having trouble with the node.js project. I am practicing a blog using node and express and i am stuck at this stage. the error message is "article.findbyid is not a function"

please look at the article.js file below

```
const express = require('express');
const Article = require('./../models/mongoose');
const { Mongoose, default: mongoose } = require('mongoose') 
const router = express()

router.get('/new', (req, res) => {
    res.render('articles/new', {article: new Mongoose(), })
})
 
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index')
})
 
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    // This is where I get the error
    const article = Article.findById(req.params.name, req.params.id);
    res.send('${req.params.id}');
})
 
router.post('/', async(req, res) => {
 
    var article = new Mongoose({ title : req.body.title, description : req.body.description, markdown : req.body.markdown })

    try {
        article = await article.save
        res.redirect('/articles/:${article.id}') }catch(e){
    
        console.log(e)
        res.render('articles/new' , {article : article})
 
    }

});

module.exports = router
```

The code in bold font is what I don't understand. I am a beginner here. what is article.findbyid does and what should be declared there. is it article.findById or something else. I have problems with the declaration I guess

Comment: Quoting is not how you show code. Any chance you can still clean that up a bit to make your code look like code? And use, say, a comment above it to mark the bit you want to highlight. Will be much more legible and we'll be able to help you much better.

Comment: Also, at a quick glance `Article` should not exists in your "bold" bit. It has not been declared yet. Later on, in another method with it's own closure, your create a Mongoose called article, which I presume is the kind of object you want to fetch stuff from the DB.

Comment: Yeah my bad. I am new at this. Sorry for that. I am still getting used to stackoverflow. Yeah, the article is what i used for the new mongoose. article is what should fetch it from the database. i have also tried article.findById and still i get the same error message. in the web dev simplified page on youtube by kyle, he has this video. I am trying that out on my end using different names as Kyle has used the keyword "article" on all the codes. "article" is a variable which requests the details from the blog.

Comment: I have cleaned it up a little bit so its more legible (newlines can help make code look more readable, as does indentation). A quick glance at the Mongoose docs implies to me that `findById` should really only have one string as an argument, the `id`. There are some options, but both `name` and `id` in your params are strings, so maybe you are just not searching the correct id? You sure you didnt mean to use `findById(req.params.name || req.params.id)` (logical OR to pick either the name param if it exists, otherwise the id param)

Comment: Thanks. Nope I am didnt meant to use it. i am following the video and working things out on my end. if you could take a look at this "https://youtu.be/1NrHkjlWVhM?t=2156" video. I have frozen it at the point where kyle declares the find by ID. i am not sure as to what argument he is using. He has used the word "article" for almost everything through out the video from constants to variables to even naming the JS file

Comment: The video does not mention `res.params.name` (or at least not in this context) so it might just be that?

Comment: yeah but what about the article.findById command he is using. Where from the argument "article" came into picture. sorry for too many questions

Comment: All I can say is that he passes in just the id, not a name as well. Also, and this might just have been you typing it out, but `findbyid` _does not exist_ as the correct name is `findById` - can't say if its that. I can't really help much more. You will try to bang your head against this until it works (trust me, its the best way to learn the more intricate ins and outs of a system!)

Comment: Sure bro. thanks a lot for this. yeah as u said i need to find it all by my own

Comment: Not all, I am willing to help but I honestly can't see it either and I have pointed out what clearly look different. Try to use `console.log` to see what is in the `article` object, or if its even an object? I am just not going to run the entire code and tutorial to see what's going wrong here - I have official work to get to as well!

Comment: Thanks bro. Sure. take your time. i will take your advice and will do the console.log thing here. I will let you know hot it goes. thanks a ton for this idea.